# What does getStdRandom $ randomR return?

Tags: haskell, random

I wrote a short Haskell program and compiled it without issues

```
import System.Random
func1=getStdRandom $ randomR ('A','Z')
main = do
  print =<< func1
```

But if I changed the tuple to (1,100), I have to add a type signature in order to successfully compile it.

```
import System.Random
func2 :: IO Int
func2=getStdRandom $ randomR (1,100)
main = do
  print =<< func2
```

The type of the functions are different.

```
Prelude System.Random> func1 = getStdRandom $ randomR ('A','Z')
Prelude System.Random> func2 = getStdRandom $ randomR (1,100)
Prelude System.Random> func3 = getStdRandom $ randomR (1,100) :: IO Int
Prelude System.Random> :t func1
func1 :: IO Char
Prelude System.Random> :t func2
func2 :: (Random a, Num a) => IO a
Prelude System.Random> :t func3
func3 :: IO Int
Prelude System.Random>
```

Could someone tell me why two similar looking tuples (Char,Char) and (Int,Int) generate different type signature functions ?

And if I moved the function, it does not compile.

```
import System.Random
main = do
print =<< getStdRandom $ randomR ('A','Z')
```

I don't know why "print =<< func1" works but "print =<< getStdRandom $ randomR ('A','Z')" does not work if func1 and "getStdRandom $ randomR ('A','Z')" are the same thing?

Thank you
eii

Answer (score 4):

When you write a number literal in Haskell it could be any of the instances of the `Num` typeclass. This includes things like `Float`, `Double`, `Int`, `Integer` etc. Therefore the compiler doesn't know which `Num` you are talking about so you must specify that you meant `Int`. Char literals on the other hand are always `Char`s so there is no need to specify the type.

Answer (score 3):

> Could someone tell me why two similar looking tuples (Char,Char) and (Int,Int) generate different type signature functions ?

A tuple like `(1, 100)` doesn't have the type `(Int, Int)` because all number literals in Haskell are polymorphic unless a specific type can be inferred from the context.

> I don't know why "print =<< func1" works but "print =<< getStdRandom $ randomR ('A','Z')" does not work if func1 and "getStdRandom $ randomR ('A','Z')" are the same thing?

It's because of operator precedence.

```
print =<< getStdRandom $ randomR ('A','Z')
```

is parsed as:

```
(print =<< getStdRandom) $ (randomR ('A','Z'))
```

What you want is:

```
print =<< (getStdRandom $ randomR ('A','Z'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Prelude System.Random> getStdRandom $ randomR (1,100) :: IO Int
88
Prelude System.Random> getStdRandom $ randomR (1,100) :: IO Double
10.275865473218671
```

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone tell me why two similar looking tuples (Char,Char) and (Int,Int) generate different type signature functions ?

In Haskell integral literals actually have type `Num t => t`:

```
Prelude> :t 1
1 :: Num t => t
```

The part before the `=>` is a type constraint. It says that the type `t` must implement the `Num` class. And the part after the `=>` is the type, in this case just `t`. This means that the literal `1` can have any type `t` that implements the `Num` class.

A type class is a way to express that a type supports a set of functions like in this case every type `a` that is an instance of (i.e. that implementing) Num must have a function `fromInteger :: Integer -> a`. Haskell now desugars all your integral literals like `1` to `fromInteger 1` where `1` is of type `Integer`.